# DSE graph schema creation

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, datastax-enterprise-graph

I understand programmatic schema creation is an upcoming feature. Guessing there will be a Schema class/API. But in the meantime, are there any provisions to create a schema via any mechanism other than the datastax studio.

I ask this because in my case, the schema should be derived from a meta-data and no manual intervention is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists a few options for programmatic schema creation today:

- [Schema API](http://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/reference/refSchemaAPI.html)
- This can be used in the [Gremlin Console](http://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/createSchemaGremlin.html) or through [Studio](http://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/createSchemaStudio.html)
- [Traversal API](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver-dse/1.4/manual/graph/) via the drivers

Are you looking for additional functionality?

Comment: Sorry. Jumped the Gun. Traversal API executeGraph methods works well. Thanks (I was previously using execute method which failed)